# Netbeans SQL syntax highlighting within a script? (e.g. PHP)

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, netbeans

When a block of SQL is enclosed in quotes in PHP (denoting a string) it would be great to have that SQL syntax highlighted. I'm looking for standard SQL highlighting at the very least, but PostgreSQL 9.1 compliant would be exactly what I need. I'm open to any suggestions no matter how complex (e.g. recompiling Netbeans) to achieve this.

Comment: I suppose suggesting PHPStorm is not an option? :)

Comment: Funnily, NetBeans does have [code completion](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/editorguide.html#cc-sql).

Answer (score 2):

All the IDE's make the sintax highlighted with auto tokenize approach [List of Parser Tokens](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php). 
In this case the SQL text and the simple text in echo/print are same token (T_STRING).
With a hard hacking in the IDE to see sintax highlighted SQL text's, all text are also afected.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime_text has that kind of feature.